# Safari pausing CSS animation delay timers when tab is not open?

Tags: css, animation, safari, synchronization, delay

I recently encountered a problem where CSS animation would desync only when running in Safari but it wouldn't always happen.

After testing for a while I found the steps to reproduce the issue. The test case with instructions are in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/Richifg/pen/vYYVPQw

```
<!-- example html -->
<span class="animation">
    <span>AAAAAAAAA</span>
    <span>BBBB</span>
    <span>CCCCCCC</span>
    <span>DDDDDDD</span>
    <span>EEEEE</span>
</span>
```

```
// example scss
.animation {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
  span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    animation-name: fadeOutIn;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
}

.animation span {
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    opacity: 0;
    &:first-child {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
        animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
        animation-delay: 4s;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
        animation-delay: 6s;
    }
    &:nth-child(5) {
        animation-delay: 8s;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeOutIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
```

I believe Safari is pausing CSS animation delays when the tab is out of focus, and when using a staggered animation pattern where several elements have the same animation with different delays, the out of focus pause can cause the animation to desync completely.

Is this expected behaviour? I only encountered this in Safari so far. Is there a workaround?

Comment: The pausing of animations in Safari of tabs out of focus is expected behavior. However, the de-syncing of the animation frames seems to be a bug with Safari. I assume this is because of the `animation-delay`.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution I found a while a go, hopefully someone will find it useful.

Only animations waiting for their `animation-delay` to finished are desynced when a safari tab is out of focus. All of these animations, no matter their `animation-delay` value, are desynced together. So the group of animations that were already running will be desynced with respect to the those that were waiting for their animation delay.

The solution consists in simply staggering your animations by adding negative `animation-delay` values. This way all animations will have started when the page loads, in fact they are considered to be running for a while to match the negative delay.

Here's an the same example fixed with negative delays:
https://codepen.io/Richifg/pen/RwweOoP